# I need to replace everything after https:// and before .com using python

Tags: python, replace

What I'm trying to do is have it replace all urls from an html file.
This is what I have done but I realized it also deletes everything else after it.

```
s = 'https://12345678.com/'

site_link = "google"
print(s[:8] + site_link)
```

It would return as `https://google`

Comment: Take a look at `re` module and using regex. Here is a good starting point: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: What's the intended output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to find all subdomains/domains from a txt file and replace them. 
depends what I put in site_link
site_link = "google"
I want it to be https://google.com
or https://subdomain.google.com

Answer (score 1):

I have made a code sample.
In this, `link_template` is a template for a link, and `*****` represents where your `site_name` will go. It might look a bit confusing at first, but if you run it you'll understand.

```
# change this to change your URL
link_template = 'https://*****.com/'

# a site name, from your example
site_name = 'google'

# this is your completed link
site_link = site_name.join(link_template.split('*****'))

# prints the result
print(site_link)
```

Additionally, you can make a function for it:

```
def name_to_link(link_template,site_name):
    return site_name.join(link_template.split('*****'))
```

And then you can use the function like this:

```
link = name_to_link('https://translate.*****.com/','google')

print(link)
```